# Find elements with class and id

Tags: javascript, jquery

You can loop through all elements where `id` contains `med_date` Like this :

```
$( $('[id^=med_date_]') ).each(function() {
```

Can you do it by `id` and `class`, something like this

```
$( $('[id^=med_date_] [class^=med_group_]') ).each(function() {
```

The id can be `med_date_1, med_date_2, med_date_3, etc`
same for the class `med_group_1, med_group_2, med_group_3, etc.`

Comment: $(".med_group_#med_date_") can do like this

Comment: $("#id.class") and in your id and class would be $("#med_date_.med_group_")

Comment: the issue is he doesn't want to find by exact id or calss, he wants id that **CONTAINS** `med_date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes sure you've just to remove the space between the selectors like :

```
$('[id^=med_date_][class^=med_group_]')
```

That the selector for **class *AND* id**, if you want **class *OR* id** you could use comma separator :

```
$('[id^=med_date_],[class^=med_group_]')
```

Hope his helps.

```js
$( $('[id^=med_date_][class^=med_group_]') ).each(function() {
   console.log($(this).text());  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id='med_date_1' class='med_group_1'>Span 1</span>
<br>
<span id='med_date_2' class='med_group_2'>Span 2</span>
<br>
<span id='med_date_3' class='med_group_3'>Span 3</span>
```

Comment: Yes, just small extra `space`, glad i could helps.

Answer (score 2):

You were close. Yes, you can use multiple selectors, you need to remove space as it indicates [Descendant Selector `(“ancestor descendant”)`](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
$('[id^=med_date_][class^=med_group_]').doSomething()
```

```js
$('[id^=med_date_][class^=med_group_]').css('color', 'green')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='med_date_1' class='med_group_1'>Span 1</span>
<br>
<span id='med_date_2' class='med_group_2'>Span 2</span>
<br>
<span id='med_date_3' class='med_group_3'>Span 3</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select all elements where `id` and `class` contains some substring you can use `[attr*=value]` attribute selector.

```
$('[id*="med_date_"][class*="med_date_"]')
```

```js
$('[id*="med_date_"][class*="med_date_"]').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="other med_date_2" id="med_date_1">Div</div>
<div class="med_date_2 other" id="med_date_2">Div</div>
```

If you are using `[class^="med_date_"]` selector that means that class value must start with `med_date_` so it won't work in case you have element with class like this `class="other med_date_2"` as you can see here

```js
$('[id^="med_date_"][class^="med_date_"]').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="other med_date_2" id="med_date_1">Div</div>
<div class="med_date_2 other" id="med_date_2">Div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("[id^=med_date_], [class^=med_group_]")
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but as @Zakaria Acharki suggests, the comma is a OR selector and leafing the space out is a AND selector.

Comment: Yes, that is true, you can use space to comma(,) based on requirement.